# How to compose regex with condition in Java?

Tags: java, regex

**Condition**:

- numbers can be either int or double (total 8 digits)
- numbers can only be separated by spaces (one or many) and commas (0 or one)
- commas can only be inside numbers (there can be no commas at the beginning and end of a line)
- there may be spaces at the beginning of the line (one or many)
- there may be spaces at the end of the line (one or many)

**What I do**:

```
([\s]*\d+(\.{1}\d+)?[\s\,\s]+){7}(\d+(\.{1}\d+)?[\s]*){1}
                    ^ this   ^
```

That's ok, except for one condition.
On this string I get `true`, but need `false`:

```java
String s1 = " 0 , 4.4 3.2,, 4.1      2 4 1 7.7";
```

I can't do this:

> Numbers can be separated by only one comma or no comma, but in this case there must be a space (one or many).

Comment: you can use `(?:,?|\s+)` for *(zero or one comma) or (1 or more spaces)*

Comment: 1. Does "total 8 numbers" mean "total 8 _digits_"?
2. Try replacing ```[\s,\s]+``` with ```(?:\s*,?\s*|\s+)``` (assuming a comma can have spaces around it)

Comment: @n199a good catch

Comment: @Gryphon, write as answer :)

Comment: @cid Shouldn't it be `(?:,|\s+)`? Otherwise, the regex would match the empty string.

Comment: @Turing85, That right `(?:\s*,?\s*|\s+)`

Comment: After looking through the regex (and the sample) your use of "numbers" was correct - sorry about that, I read it incorrectly at first!

Comment: @Gryphon, everything is good. I changed after your comment

Comment: @Turing85 yep indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one I came up with for the spaces/commas (also removed some redundant parts):

```
Pattern.compile("([\\s]*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s*,\\s*|\\s+)){7}(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?[\\s]*)");
```

Seems to do what you want with the sample you provided, at least. (The use of `{1}` is generally implied for the places you used it, so I removed those)